# Blowing cool air into attic crawl Space

Tags: hvac

I just had a new metal roof installed. I paid extra to have baffles installed to facilitate soffit ventilation. The contractor installed the baffles but they didn't reach above my blown in insulation, thus doing very little to ventilate the crawl space. I have been considering blowing cooler air into the space via 4" duct in hopes of forcing hot air out the ridge vent. Any thoughts/opinions are welcome.

Comment: Is there a gap between the insulation and the underside of the roof down at the soffit, and is the soffit clear of insulation? As long as there's a clear path from the soffit up to the ridge vent then the natural ventilation should work. Can you [Edit] your question and show us a pic or 2?

Comment: Take a leaf blower or compressed air hose to the soffit vents to blow a path clear might work to restore the venting. Either that, or crawl in and reach down by hand to clear the baffle/vent space.

Comment: What's the question, exactly? Why not just clear the baffles? It should be fairly easy to carefully compress the insulation against the roof on those locations.

Answer (score 0):

As you already know, attic vents (baffles) is a passive ventilation. It mostly relies on thermal/natural air movement. The hot hair will expand towards colder air outside.

Adding an active air movement by means of a fan will certainly help here.

Normally attic fans are 20 Inches, so not sure home much you 4 inch will do but it is better than nothing. Also the fans usually operate in exhaust mode.

It is all in CFM. How much air is cycled in given time.

Just ignore me, and use what you can to force move the air.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into a solar powered fan.   You only need it to run on hot sunny days and there is less wiring.

Answer (score 0):

I will take a SWAG and say be careful blowing air into your attic, That will place a lot of force on your ceiling drywall. I was told many years ago you always suck the air out of an attic, it keeps the ceiling in place. The force would be the pressure of the fan into the attic per square (inches, meters, etc) times the number of squares in the ceiling.

Doing this using inches 10' x 10' = 100 square feet = 14,400 square inches. 1 inch of water = 0.03613 psig per sq in.

Comment: From energy principles, a somewhat weak fan can't exert large loads over large areas.